# Outlook: Unable to view/open email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, certificate

I get the following error message when I try to open/view one particular email which I received recently from Outlook 2003 with all the latest service pack installed but I have never associated any certificates with Outlook. I have never had this problem previously. Neither did I changed any settings. What is the cause?

"*Can't open this item. Your Digital ID name can not be found by the underlying security system.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has likely sent you a signed and/or encrypted message which you cannot open as you do not have the public key. I don't suspect this affects all of your email, does it? Maybe the email was accidentally sent to the wrong recipient. If you can see the sender, ask them to send another copy in plain text and discard the last one.

Comment: No it doesn't affect the other emails. Only this one.

Comment: My guess is someone accidentally sent you an encrypted email. You won't be able to read it without the proper key to decrypt it so I'd just delete it if you don't know the sender.

Comment: You're very welcome!